# find string within excel formula text

Tags: excel

is there a way to catch all cells containing `#REF!` in their functions (not in their result), preferably without using vba?

example:
i would like to catch cells containing e.g. this:

`=+SUBSTITUTE("#REF!","#REF!","text")`

1) since the displayed result of the cell is "text", which is not an error, `=+ISERROR()` won't work.

2) i have also tried `=+SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*ref*",A:A))*1)` but that doesn't work either.

3) the only thing i was able to achieve, was to identify the first cell in a column containing "#" with the use of `=+MATCH("#",A:A,-1)` but that's only half of the answer since i can't/ do know how (?) to use it over several columns.

4) last but not least, i'm on excel 2010, so no `=ISFORMULA()` available.

any ideas/ help will be greatly appreciated!
thanks!

Comment: `#REF!` is an `Error` value, it's not equivalent to text string `"#REF!"`. Can you re-state your problem -- it's difficult to understand why you would try to use a `Substitute` function on string literals in this manner, or what the expected result of such usage would be, etc.

Comment: You can use `Ctrl+F` with the option to search formula,s this will return cells which include either the error value `#REF!"` or the literal `"#REF!"`.

Comment: David, i didnt't think of that when stating my problem. Tried to make it easier to understand but only made things worst. Sorry. I am using an add-in custom formula which is =GetData($B$1:$B$6,#REF!,O$6:O$7,O$8,"100"). The problem is this formula queries a database by looking at the cell ranges provided and just ignores the #REF! part, thus returning wrong amounts, without any alert. That's what I'm trying to catch.

Comment: David, i didnt't think of that when stating my problem. Tried to make it easier to understand but only made things worst. Sorry. I am using an add-in custom formula which is =GetData($B$1:$B$6,#REF!,O$6:O$7,O$8,"100"). The problem is this formula queries a database by looking at the cell ranges provided and just ignores the #REF! part, thus returning wrong amounts, without any alert. That's what I'm trying to catch.

Comment: the answer that @pawelty provided leverages the `Find/Replace` functionality and I think that should help you do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about find & replace and substituting `"=GetData"` with `"^^GetData"` (replacing the `=` with some character(s) which don't exist in your formulae)? Then you can use `SEARCH` on it and once you're done you replace back `"^^"` with `"="`.